# In app billing: reset static response to not purchased

Tags: android

I'm testing in app billing in my app with static responses https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html
I'm using android.test.purchased to test my purchase, the first time i was able to fakely buy it, but now it lists as purchased and i can't test it anymore.

Is there a way to reset that purchased state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using API version 3, it handles all the products as managed products. Managed means it is purchased once. So it means you need to consume that product first and tell google that the item purchased is consumed. Then it will be available for purchase again. Please Visit http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume

Answer (score 1):

have you tried reinstalling the app inside you emulator or on your device?

i think this will be the correct result

for fast uninstalling use the adb command

```
cd ../android-sdk/platform-tools

adb uninstall your.package.name
```

Comment: I've tryied already unistalling, deleting the files and cache from the app, but nothing helps